# Swift 1.2 to swift 2: Objective C method conflicts with optional requirement method

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to develop an app that accesses the phone's camera based on a tutorial I found online (https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift#next_section). However my camera extension at the imagePickerController function keeps throwing up this error:

> Objective-C method '`imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`' provided by method '`imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`' conflicts with optional requirement method `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`

This is the code where the error was thrown

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {}
```

The affected code block is as shown below

```
// Camera Extension
extension SelfieCollectionViewController : UINavigationControllerDelegate,     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
func displayCameraControl() {
var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.delegate = self
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
  imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

  if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front) {
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
  } else {
    imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Rear
  }
} else {
  imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
}

self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
}
}
```

The full code block can be found here (https://codeshare.io/UurWD) at line 111.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) { }
```

with

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) { }
```